# Vue JS Using local variable without defining in data() function

Tags: vue.js, variables

I am a beginner to Vue JS. I have to use a variable inside a component whose value changes often.
So when I declare and define it under data() the following warn is coming in Chrome console
[image]

Since when there is a change in data() variables automatically Vue framework calls render function.

Is there any way to declare and use a variable other than declaring it in data() method ??

```
<template>
    <ul>
         <div v-for="(list,index) in itemlist" :key="index">
           <div v-if="!isFirstCharSame(list.label)" >{{ firstChar }} </div>
            <li>
              <span>{{ list.label }}</span>
            </li> 
         </div>  
       </ul> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        itemlist: [
                  {"label":"Alpha"},
                  {"label":"Beta"},
                  {"label":"Charlie"},
                  {"label":"Delta"}],
        firstChar:"$"
      }
    },
    methods : {
      isFirstCharSame: function(str) {
      if(str.startsWith(this.firstChar)) {
        return true;
      }
      this.firstChar = str.charAt(0);
      return false;
    }
    }

}
</script>
```

Expected output should be like this

[image: Expected Output]

Inside Group A It should display all the elements starting with A

Comment: Declaring it in data is probably not the root cause of the issue.  You'll have to show us code to help.

Comment: @StevenB.I have attached the code. here I am changing the firstChar variable name when I am looping through itemList

Comment: What are you trying to do with the above template? Order the list alphabetically?

Comment: @MichaelMano Yes along with the first character as a separate div so that it looks like grouping

Answer (score 2):

Below we will render using a computed property to make sure its sorted alphabetically and then render your first char. Though You should be using grouping imo.

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <div v-for="(list, index) in sortedlist" :key="`people_${index}`">
           <div v-if="!isFirstCharSame(list.label)" >{{ firstChar }} </div>
            <li>
              <span>{{ list.label }}</span>
            </li> 
         </div> 
    </ul> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        itemlist: [
            {"label":"Alpha"},
            {"label":"Beta"},
            {"label":"Charlie"},
            {"label":"Delta"},
        ],
        firstChar: '',
      };
    },
    methods: {
        isFirstCharSame(char) {
            if (str.startsWith(this.firstChar)) {
                return true;
            }
            this.firstChar = str.charAt(0);
            return false;
        },
    },
    computed: {
        sortedList() {
            return this.itemList.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.label > b.label) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (b.label > a.label) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

And yes, You can update your data any time you wish and the component will do a re render to reflect it.

Comment: I need to show the first character of the whole group and then I need to show the elements name. But I was not able to find any other logic for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare variables in your component within your methods or inside computed properties, etc., but they won't be reachable from the template or the rest of the code nor they would be reactive.

The only way for them to be reactive and reachable from the higher scope is adding the `data` property to the component in the following way:

```js
data: function () {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'    
    }
  },
```

or

```js
data () {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'    
    }
  },
```

Besides this, the reason of your error is that you are mutating the state of your variables inside the render. When this happens, Vue re-renders the template because the values have mutated and calls again to the function and *voilà*: there you have an infinite loop.

You should probably check the function you are calling and try to replace the changing variables from the `data` property with local variables that take their data from the actual `data` variables.

Comment: Because I needed to group it as shown I have to store the last entry permanently.